# Normal subgroup of order $p$ is in the center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that in a group of order $p^2$ ($p$ a prime), a normal subgroup of order $p$ lies in the center.   (Since this is Exercise 2.9.6 from Herstein's Topics in Algebra, there are some restrictions on what I can use.  This section is on Cayley's theorem.  I can show, using the class equation, that $Z(G)>1$ and $G$ is abelian, but I don't want to use the class equation yet.)

If $H$ is a subgroup of order $p$, since $|G|$ does not divide $i(H)!$, $H$ contains a nontrivial proper subgroup $K$ of $G$. Since $p$ is a prime, $K$ must equal $H$.  Hence $H$ is normal.  Why is it in the center?

Comment: Let $G$ act on $H$ by conjugation; count the fixed points.

Comment: The proof provided by @Jyrki Lahtonen, actually works for every $p-$group $G$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This type of exercises are difficult to judge in a forum like this, because we need to know precisely, what has been covered up to that point. Many posters are then inclined to use extra bits they have learned (later in a similar course).

I get the feeling that the following is what might have been expected. This is just fleshing out the hint in Steve D's comment, so I make it a CW.

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of order $p$. We know (Lagrange's theorem) that $H$ is cyclic. Let $g$ be a generator. Let $x$ be any element of $G$. By normality of $H$ we know that
$$
xgx^{-1}=g^k,
$$
for some integer $k, 0<k<p$. Conjugation by $x$ is an automorphism of $H$, so
$xg^{t}x^{-1}=g^{tk}$ for all integers $t$. In particular we get that
$$
x^2g x^{-2}=x(xgx^{-1})x^{-1}=xg^kx^{-1}=g^{k^2}.
$$
An obvious induction then proves that
$$
x^tgx^{-t}=g^{k^t}
$$
for all natural numbers $t$. But, again by Lagrange's theorem $x^{p^2}=1$. Therefore
$$
g=1g1^{-1}=g^{k^{p^2}}.
$$
As $g$ is of order $p$, this means that $1\equiv k^{p^2}\pmod p$. But two applications of Little Fermat tell us that
$$
k\equiv k^p \equiv k^{p^2}\equiv 1\pmod p.
$$
Recalling the constraint $0<k<p$ we can conclude that $k=1$. Therefore $x$ and $g$ commute. Obviously then $x$ commutes with all the powers of $g$. As $x$ was arbitray, we have shown that $H\le Z(G)$.

Comment: I see that your answer is quite delicate and marvellous, but I fail to perceive why this answer flashed out from the comment of Steve D. Per chance some explanations could be provided? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I was just looking at the conjugate action. Something tells me that Steve D's suggestion can lead to a simpler argument, too. Gotta rush now.

Comment: This is actually slightly different than what I suggested.  Instead, if $G$ acts on $H$ via conjugation, you have a group of order $p^2$ acting on a set of size $p$. So $G$ is being mapped into $S_p$, where each element of the image has order dividing $p^2$.  But $G$ fixes one point of $H$ (the identity), and so it must fix at least $p$ points...

Comment: Well, so it seems that the $2$ in the power of $p$ is not of any significance.. So will this hold for any $p-$group?

Comment: Well spotted @Qwerty ! It certainly looks like the argument survives. So a normal subgroup of order $p$ of any (finite) $p$-group is in the center.

Comment: Very elegant solution! But let me ask the question: Why $k$ lies strictly between $0$ and $p$ i.e. $0<k<p$?

Comment: @RFZ $xgx^{-1}$ is a non-trivial element of the subgroup $H$ generated by $g$.

Comment: Thanks a lor for answer :)

Comment: Nice solution.  You only need lil' Fermat once, since obviously $p^2\equiv1\pmod{p-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

If $G$ were cyclic it would be abelian, and we’d be done. Suppose it’s not. Then every element is of order $p$ by Lagrange’s theorem. And every subgroup of size $p$ is normal by Herstein’s lemma 2.9.1.

Subgroup $H$ must be cyclic having elements of order $p$. Then any two elements of $H$ commute.

Suppose $k\not\in H$. Then $k$ generates a group $K$ of size $p$, and this group is normal (using the first paragraph).

Now $H\cap K=\{e\}$ since it’s a subgroup of size $<p$. Then, for any $h\in H,$ $hkh^{-1}k^{-1} \in H\cap K$ using the normalcy of both subgroups (eg $hkh^{-1}\in K$ since $K$ is normal, and so on). But then
$$hkh^{-1}k^{-1} = e \Rightarrow hk = kh.$$

Comment: Your proof shows only elements in H and K are.commute

Comment: @ChinnapparajR, this proof works for any h in H and any k not in H, which is what we need to show that H is in the center. (It is not about a specific subgroup K, it is for any k outside H.)

Comment: Im just confused... Now its fine...Thank u

Answer (score 1):

If $H\not\subset Z$ then  $H\cap Z=1$. Hence $HZ$ is subgroup of order $\ge p^2$, i.e. $HZ=G$ and $G$ is Abelian.

Comment: Why is $|HZ| \ge p^2$?  This follows if $|Z| \ge p$, which hasn't been shown.  Why is $G$ abelian?

Comment: $HZ$ is a $p$-group, so its order is $\ge p^2$. Since $H$ is  Abelian and $Z$ is central, so $HZ=G$ is  Abelian.

Comment: $p$-groups aren't defined yet.  Can a $p$-group have order $p$?

Comment: @user64647, but you said you can show $\,|Z(G)|>1\,$ so it **must** be $\,|Z(G)|=p\,,\,p^2\,$...!

Comment: @DonAntonio: I said I can prove $|Z(G)|>1$ if I used the class equation.  Is there another way to prove this?  Just asking, because (as I mentioned above) this exercise on $H \le Z$ is asked in a section before the class equation.

Comment: You didn't write "if I **used**"...Anyway, I can't think of anything simpler than the class equation to show that the center of a finite $\,p$-groups is non-trivial. Sorry.

Comment: ok.  Perhaps some of the exercises assume you know the material in later sections already or that you can derive those results yourself.  I couldn't do this without the class equation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it must be $\,Z(G)=G\Longleftrightarrow G\,$ is abelian, in this case. You only need the easy

**Lemma:** For *any* group $\,G\,$ , the quotient $\,G/Z(G)\,$ cannot be cyclic non-trivial.

The above says that $\,G/Z(G)\,\,\,\text{cyclic}\;\Longleftrightarrow \;G\,$ is abelian...

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be the normal subgroup of size $p$. By Langrange's theorem $H$ must be generated by an element say $g \in G$ s.t. $g^p=e$.

Since $H$ is normal in $G$, $G/H$ is a group and has order $p$. Let this group be generated by $Hb$. Then $e \neq b \notin H$ and $Hb^p =H$. We assume here that $b^p=e$ otherwise order of $b$ is $p^2$ and $G$ is generated by $b$ meaning $G=Z(G)$.

At this point it is clear that $G$ is generated by $a$ and $b$ because $G$ can be partitioned into cosets of $H$ that have elements that are products of $a$ and $b$.

$H$ is normal in $G \implies bab^{-1} = a^i$ (for some $i$). $\iff ba= a^ib$.

Consider a subgroup $H_2$ generated by $b$ in $G.$ Since $b \neq e$ and $b^p=e$, $o(H_2)=p$.

As $|G| =p^2$ does not divide $i(H_2)! = p!$ $H_2$ must be normal in $G$.

$H_2$ normal in $G \implies a^{-1}ba = b^j $ (for some $j$) $\iff ba = ab^j$.

$ba = a^ib$ and $ba = ab^j$ imply that $i=j=1$ and $ba = ab$.

Thus $G$ is abelian or $G=Z(G)$.