# Eliminate contradiction in the definition of group of order $p^2$ with a normal subgroup of order $p$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Let us define a group $G =\langle a,b \mid a^p =e, b^p=e, ba=a^2b \rangle $ where $p$ is a prime.  It can be deduced that $o(G) = p^2$. The subgroup $N$ generated by the element $a$ is of the order $p$ and is normal in $G$  because $bab^{-1} =a^2  $.

We know that if $N$ is a normal subgroup with $o(N)=p$ of the group $G$ with $o(G)=p^2$, then it must be that $N \subset Z(G)$ [shown here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318579/normal-subgroup-of-order-p-is-in-the-center). But in that case $ab=ba$ and $ba = a^2b$ imply $a=e$ which is not true.

What is causing the contradiction ?

I assume that one can define a group with generators and relations, where the relation can be any set. Is this correct ?

---

Edit : Let the group be defined as given. Without using the fact that $ N \subset Z(G)$ when $o(N)=p$ and $o(G)=p^2$, prove that $a=e$.

Comment: " It can be deduced that $o(G) = p^2$." Really?

Comment: @AnginaSeng : What is the the size of G then ?

Comment: @emmy you have to be careful: if you see $a^p=e$ in a presentation, that does not imply that $a$ has order $p$, it only implies that $a$ has order dividing $p$. Similarly, it is more or less obvious that $G$ has order dividing $p^2$, but the proof you give shows that $a=e$ and in fact, $G$ has order $p$. I don't know why you say that $a=e$ is not true.

Answer (score 3):

The proof you give is essentially correct, except every time you say something has order $x$, you should say it has order at most $x$, or even order dividing $x$.

A corrected proof goes as follows:  the subgroup generated by $a$ is normal, and it has order dividing $p$. The quotient has order dividing $p$ as well, so the whole group has order dividing $p^2$. It follows that $G$ is abelian (I'm guessing $p$ is meant to be a prime, judging by your link, although I think we can still make things work even if $p$ is not a prime), from which we conclude that $a$ is the identity. The whole presentation then collapses to $G=\langle b|b^p=e\rangle$, so $G$ has order $p$.

Comment: I am trying to disprove the statement "N normal in G of order p and G of order $p^2$ implies $N \subset Z(G) $". So if you can prove that the example I constructed is wrong using another method it would be great.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Assuming $p$ is prime (which is something you should clarify), if $G$ has order $p^2$, then it is abelian, all subgroups are normal, and the center is the whole group. So you will not be able to disprove the statement above, because it is correct. I don't know what you mean by "the example you constructed".